# How can I align the dropdown items to left when in responsive mode?

Tags: html, css

[image: ****]
This is the dropdown items that align to right when responsive, I just want to align it to left when in responsive mode.

```
<div class="dropdown">
           <i class="far fa-user-circle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="font-size:36px"></i>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="float-right fas fa-unlock-alt pr-2"></i>CHANGE PASSWORD</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="float-right fa fa-user pr-2"></i>PROFILE</a></li>
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="float-right fa fa-sign-out-alt pr-1"></i>LOGOUT</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in responsive mode?"

Comment: when in mobile view i mean when i inspect

Comment: can you provide your CSS code?

Comment: I already solved, I just add "dropdown-menu-lg-right" next to "dropdown-menu-left", thanks

Answer (score 0):

To align the dropdown to the left when in responsive mode, you can add a media query in your CSS code.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
  .dropdown-menu {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

This code targets screens with a maximum width of 767 pixels and sets the right property of the .dropdown-menu element to auto and the left property to 0, which positions the dropdown menu to the left side of its parent element.